# Perl's OpenAPI::Client - how to pass additionalProperties in OpenAPI GET query request?

Tags: perl, openapi, mojolicious

I'm trying to pass filter variables in a GET request to an OpenAPI route with this specification:

```
  - in: query
    name: params
    schema:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
    style: form
    explode: true
```

I've tried various different ways of passing the data at request time:

```
my $client = OpenAPI::Client->new(...);

my $tx = $client->findApps({
    params => { 'id' =>  '1' }
});

my $tx = $client->findApps({ 'id' =>  '1' });
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: This version looks correct: `params => { 'id' =>  '1' }`. Do you get an error or something? It might be that OpenAPI::Client does not support OAS3 `style` and `explode` for query serialization.